# How to make a while loop with a range of numbers

Tags: python, while-loop, range

I am trying to make a loop which will continue to ask for inputs unless a number out side of 0-100 is entered.

posting homework description as well to avoid getting shit on again.
In this assignment, you will design and implement a Python program that has three while loops.

The last set of readings is for humidity values(integers) between 0 and 100 (both values included).Any value outside this range is a sentinel value. The program computes the latest of the humidity readings. There need not be any readings at all because the first line itself may be outside the range 0 through 100. Your code should not fail even if there are no humidity readings.

```
while humid in range(0,100):
```

this is what I have right now, and it stops after one number.

Comment: In Python you don't need to instantiate variable type with 'humid = int()'. Remove this line and add 'humid=0' before the while condition.

Comment: ...but note that, while unnecessary, both `humid=int()` and `humid=0` should have the same behavior (setting the `humid` variable to integer 0).

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python input integer", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.  Also, you should learn to use a `for` loop -- that's the functionality you're trying to implement.

Comment: i have humid=0 at the front end. not sure how to post my whole code in a comment without it looking cancerous, other wise I would.

my home works states I need to use while loops, otherwise I would try other things.

Comment: i am not having issues with inputs and integers. It takes the inputs, the problem is it only does it once.

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a string value, which will never be in the numeric range 0-100, so your loop exits immediately.

As a first step to fixing your code, you can immediately convert the result of `input()` by wrapping it in a call to `int()`, like this:

```
humid = int(input('Enter humidity: '))
```

Comment: while temp != "":
        temp = int()
        temp_num += 1
        temp_total += temp
        temp = input('Enter temperature: ')

this code works though with the input.

Comment: `temp = int()` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: well without it it wasnt allowing me to press enter to cancel the loop. it works with it in there. using int(input()) wasnt working either.